# Can one use inline validation rules, and config file based validation rules simultaneously?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

PHP / CodeIgniter.

In order to set up a form that validates the logic: "either one, or both, of the fields is required" I have to use inline form validation like this (source is  http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/136417/#672903):

```
if ( ! $this->input->post('email'))
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', 'required');
}
else
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', '');
}

// If no phone number, email is required
if ( ! $this->input->post('phone'))
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');
}
else
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'valid_email');
}
```

But I have a whole lot of other forms where I'd prefer to use config file based form validation.

I cannot think of a way to get the two to co-exist, and I don't really want to now go and bring all my rules into the code body.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using both types? In the code above you're only using inline. And do you intend on using them together for the same form or only either/or per form?

Comment: I am intending to use them together in the same application, but not the same form. Any one form will use one of the two types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rule sets from the config file or inline rules just fine in the same application.

config/form_validation.php

```
$config = array(
    'ruleset1' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|alpha'
        ),
    )
);
```

controller example

```
    public function ruleset()
    {
        if ($this->input->post())
        {
            // runs validation using ruleset1 from the config
            if ($this->form_validation->run('ruleset1') == FALSE)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    public function inline_rules()
    {
        if ($this->input->post())
        {
            // ignores the config and uses the inline rules
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|alpha_numeric');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: I found that trying to mix them for the same form does not work. Specifying inline rules and a ruleset on the same form will cause the ruleset to be ignored completely and the inline rules to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in your libraries name it `MY_Form_validation`

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation 
{

public function __construct($rules = array())
{
   parent::__construct($rules);
   $this->CI->lang->load('MY_form_validation');
}


function email_phone($str)
{
  if(!$str)
  {   
    // if POST phone exists validate the phone entries   
    //validation for phone
    return TRUE;
  }else{
    //if no phone was entered
    //check the email
    $email = $this->input->post('email'));

    //use the systems built in validation for the email
    //set your error message here

    return $this->valid_email($email) && $this->required($email);
  }
}
}

//or set the message here
$this->form_validation->set_message('email_phone','Please enter either an email or phone.');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', 'email_phone');
```